# Finding vertex with right angle using dot products

Tags: linear-algebra

> Given that $A(3, 0, 2), B(4, 3, 0)$ and $C(8, 1, -1)$ are vertices of a right triangle. At which vertex is the right angle?

How can I solve this dot product problem? I know that if dot product is zero they are perpendicular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the direction vectors:

$$\vec u:= \vec{AB}=(1,3,-2)\\\vec v:=\vec{AC}=(5,1,-3)\\\vec w:=\vec{BC}=(4,-2,-1)$$

Well, now what two direction vectors' dot product is zero?

Comment: Oh okay. i got it, it is B. Thank you. I was calculating AB  <1, 0, -2>

Comment: @Saad That is correct: $\;\vec u\cdot\vec w=0\implies B\;$ is the vertex at which the straight angle is.

Answer (score 0):

You just calculate the dot products of the vectors that represent the edges and see which one yields zero. To get the vector for the edge between $A$ and $B$, subtract the vector for $A$ from the vector for $B$.

The formula for the dot product is
$$(a,b,c)\cdot(x,y,z)=ax+by+cz$$

Now you have two edges whose dot product is $0$. The point whose angle is $90$ degrees is the one that is on both edges. I'm getting that the answer is $B$

Comment: I think one needs the *direction* vectors' dot product, not the vectors' themselves.

Comment: In my case none of the vectors yield zero. I know i'm doing something wrong in calculating the vectors. I calculated AB, AC and BC. @Stella

Comment: Yup. I read it quickly and thought those were edge vectors not coordinate vectors. I fixed my answer